# Trying to iterate over a "subdictionaries" in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am having a lot of trouble trying to iterate over a mongo collection that have other ""subdictionaries" on it.

Basically, inside the structure of my collection I have an object that represents other Strings:

For instance:

I am trying to get the **stats** over this collection:

[image: MongoDB Structure]

This is the code I am using for now:

```html
cursor = mycol.find(
    {}, {'_id': 1, 'stats.total': 1, 'stats.additions': 1, 'stats.deletions': 1})

with open('commits.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    fields = ['id', 'stats.total', 'stats.additions', 'stats.deletions']
    write = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=fields)
    write.writeheader()
    for commits in cursor:
        id = commits['_id']
        for stats in commits['stats']:
            flattened_record = {
                '_id': id,
                'stats.total': stats['total'],
                'stats.additions': stats['additions'],
                'stats.deletions': stats['deletions']
            }
            write.writerow(flattened_record)
```

I keep getting the TypeError: string indices must be integers and the type of stats object seem to be an unicode.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks for your time,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by iterating over the stats first and then checking the total, additions and deletions separately:

```html
if 'stats' in commits:
    stats = commits['stats']
    for key in stats:
        if key == 'deletions':
            deletions = stats[key]
        elif key == 'additions':
            additions = stats[key]
        else:
            total = stats[key]
```